# Constructing matrices from quantum states expressed in the bra-ket notation

Tags: matrix, physics

Written in the bra-ket notation, I have a (quantum) state/vector of the form:

> $$ |\alpha, J \rangle = \Bigg [\frac{\alpha}{(1 + |\alpha|^2)}\Bigg ]^{J} \sum_{m = - J}^{J} \sqrt{\binom{2J}{J+m}} \alpha^{m} |J, m \rangle,$$

where $\alpha = e^{i \phi} \tan(\theta/2)$ and $J$ is either an integer or a half integer. $m$ goes up in steps of $1$ from $J$ to $-J$.

Now this state/vector has a representation in the form of a column vector of dimension $(2J + 1) \times 1$. The rule to get the column vector is as follows: for $m = J$, put the resulting term in the first row of the column vector; for $m = J - 1$, put the resulting term in the second row of the column vector;...;for $m = -J$, put the resulting term in the $2J + 1$ th row of the column vector.

Now if $\theta$ and $\phi$ have beeen specified, each term will be a complex number in general. For the moment, assume that $\alpha$ isn't specified; after doing some matrix multiplications, I'll optimize over $\theta$ and $\phi$.

My main question for now is: how do I tell *Mathematica* to construct a $(2J + 1) \times 1$ column vector, according to the aforementioned rule, after I have initialized the value of $J$ in the program?

I'd be great if someone could provide examples with codes.

#### Edit

When I defined the state using:

```
α = 0;
χ = π/2;
J = 1

Clear[ψ]
ψ[α_, χ_] := Exp[I α]*Tan[χ/2];

coherentstate[α_, χ_] := 
  ((ψ[α, χ])/(1 + Abs[ψ[α, χ]]^2))^(2 J) 
    Sum[(ψ[α, χ])^(m) Sqrt[Binomial[2 J, J + m]], {m, -J, J, 1}];
```

and run

```
Matrix[α_, χ_] := Table[coherentstate[α, χ], {m, 2 J + 1}]
MatrixForm[Matrix[α, χ]]
```

I get as the output:

[image]

Apparently, in each entry of the column vector, I am getting the COMPLETE sum. How do I tweak my code to get only the first entry in the sum as the first term in the column vector; second in the second and as on.

#### Second Edit

```
coherentstate[α_, χ_, m_] := 
  ((ψ[α, χ])/(1 + Abs[ψ[α, χ]]^2))^(2 J)* (ψ[α, χ])^(m) Sqrt[Binomial[2 J, J + m]];
```

I want to run a do loop to evaluate the expressions, assign them to new expressions and then use table to make the matrix. When I run:

```
 Do[Evaluate[coherentstate[α, χ, m]], {m, -J, J, 1}]
```

I get nothing as the output.

How can I use this approach to construct the matrix?

#### Third Edit

When I replace `Evaluate` with `Print`, Mathematica prints the relevant expressions. I'm unsure how to augment the `Do` loop command to label the printed expressions so I can easily use the table command then to table out the list of labeled expressions -- labeled after ye do loop

Comment: Just use `Table` with `m` as the index. Look up `Table` in the documentation please.

Comment: @march Please see the edit.

Comment: Before voting to close it, please see the edit.

Comment: I would just have done `Table[(a/(1 + Abs[a]^2))^j Sqrt[Binomial[2 j, j + m]] a^m, {m, 
  j, -j, -1}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to treat the kets in your `Sum` as basis vectors in the conversion to a matrix. Let me first correct your starting point to this:

```
α = 0;
χ = Pi/2;
J = 1

Clear[ψ]
ψ[α_, χ_] := Exp[I α]*Tan[χ/2];

coherentstate[α_, χ_] := ((ψ[α, χ])/(1 + 
        Abs[ψ[α, χ]]^2))^(2 J) Sum[(ψ[α, χ])^(m)*
          Sqrt[Binomial[2 J, J + m]] Ket[J, m], {m, -J, J, 1}];
```

Here, I added the `Ket` in the sum where you had them in the $\LaTeX$ version but not in your code.

Now the trick is to convert the ket symbols into canonical unit vectors corresponding to their position in the basis. Since we would like the highest `m` to appear first, I use a rule that assigns the `Table` of `Ket`s to unit vectors in descending order:

```
Matrix[α_, χ_] := 
 coherentstate[α, χ] /. 
  Table[Ket[J, m] -> List /@ UnitVector[2 J + 1, J - m + 1], {m, J, -J, -1}]

MatrixForm[Matrix[α, χ]]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \frac{1}{4} \\
>  \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \\
>  \frac{1}{4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

So I replaced your `Matrix` conversion function by a replacement rule, and the resulting unit vectors then appear inside `Sum` and get added up vectorially to obtain the desired column vector. If you look at the output of

```
Matrix[α, χ]
```

> `{{1/4},{1/(2 Sqrt[2])},{1/4}}`

you can also see that I specifically made the result a column vector by adding an additional `List` level. This is done in the `Table` construct of `Matrix`.

If you don't need the added list level, a simpler formulation of `Matrix` is this:

```
Matrix[α_, χ_] := 
 coherentstate[α, χ] /. 
  Table[Ket[J, m] -> UnitVector[2 J + 1, J - m + 1], {m, J, -J, -1}]
```

The output in `MatrixForm` will be the same as above, but it's now a one-level list.

Comment: Please check the second edit. I was trying a different approach but I couldn't make any progress with it as well. Any advice?

Comment: That second approach is worse than the first one because you're using `Do` incorrectly. Replace `Do` by `Table`.

Comment: Oh, all right. Let me try that in the morning then. I'll update this post if need be -- your approach is great, but I'm afraid I don't understand the syntax/approach in the matrix command, so I'd like to pursue with my alternative approach and see if I can do it another way.

Comment: I simplified the code for `Matrix` as much as I could now. Hopefully it's more understandable. It's also shorter.